# MySQL retrieve no of users a user has of user resultset

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables users and parents.

1. Each user has a unique id and a parent id(this is one who referred him to website).
2. Parent id of root user is 0.
3. Users that have same parent id are childrens of that id

**users**
*id

name

email*

**parents**
*id

parentId

joiningAmount*

i want a query in which i will give **id of a parent.**

This query should return all of its children with following information

id, name, email, joiningAmount, (**No of Childrens this user has**)

Is it possible to do this in one query?
If not how should i normalize database in order to complete this in one query.
Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The users table will contain all the user information

Suppose this is users table.

```
id  name    email
1   Admin   admin@web.com
2   John    John@web1.com
3   Larry   Larry@web2.com
4   Jone    Jone@web3.com
```

Registration is possible only by referral.
As admin is not referred by anyone his parentId is 0.
Suppose admin refers larry and john(thus their parent ids are 1) and john bring another user from his referral whose name his jone(thus his parent id is that of john) then parents table should look like this.

Joining amount can be ignored for now as its just part of application.

```
id  parentId  joinAmount
1   0        1000
2   1        1000
3   1        1000
4   2        1000
```

so now i want a query to which if i pass an id of 1(admins id) it should return his children's

```
id, name, email, joiningAmount, (**No of Childrens this user has**)

2, John, John@web1.com, 1000, 1(as john has 1 child)
3, Larry, Larry@web2.com, 1000, 0
```

Comment: yes, possible. Look into `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: can you please provide me the sql?

Comment: Those two tables, I do not see the relationship. `parentId` inside `parents` is a little recursive and doesn't seem to point to the `users` table

Comment: What is joiningAmount?  Is that the number of children or is that something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the answer by [Unamata Sanatarai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2119863/unamata-sanatarai), here's the query:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, users.email, users.joiningAmount, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users AS children WHERE children.parent_id = users.id ) AS children_count 
FROM users WHERE users.parent_id = 3
```

Comment: this query worked well after puttin all fields in single table.
Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest placing it into just one database like so

```
users
- id
- parent_id
- name
- email
- joiningAmount
```

That way you have only one database and you retrieve everything with a query like:

```
SELECT id, name, email, joiningAmount FROM users WHERE parent_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't change the tables the way suggested (which you probably should) then the appropriate query would be:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, users.email, parents.joiningAmount,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parents P WHERE P.parentId=users.id) 
FROM users,parents
WHERE users.id=parents.id;
```